# JavaScript get one property from an object inside of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of movies objects with the properties: movieName, grade, and position. For example these objects look like:

```
var movies = [ { movieName: "bee movie", grade: 3, position 1},
               { movieName: "Shrek", grade: 5, position: 2} ];
```

I want to get the movieName property of an object. To decide which object from the movies array I want the movieName from I create a variable named arrayPosition which is a random number between 0 and the length of the array - 1:

```
arrayPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length );
```

For example:

```js
var movies = [{
    movieName: "Incredibles",
    grade: 4,
    position: 1
  },
  {
    movieName: "Bolt",
    grade: 5,
    position: 2
  }
];

const arrayPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length);

console.log(movies[arrayPosition].movieName);
```

In this case I would like it to console either "Incredibles" or "Bolt" depending on if arrayPosition is 0 or 1 but it only consoles undefined.

I have seen solutions to similar problems but in those cases the position of the object in the array was not a variable but a decided number. For some reason this difference make it not work. How do I get only the movieName property from an object in the array?

Comment: it should console.log correctly either 0 or 1 index

Comment: Apart from not declaring `arrayPosition` it looks correct, why not make your code above into a working snippet?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? Your code looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your example code works correctly.

```js
var movies = [
  { movieName: "bee movie", grade: 3, position: 1},
  { movieName: "Shrek", grade: 5, position: 2},
  { movieName: "Incredibles", grade: 4, position: 1}, 
  { movieName: "Bolt", grade: 5, position: 2}
];

var arrayPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length)
console.log(movies[arrayPosition].movieName)
```

If you knew that you always wanted to `console.log` the title of the 2nd movie in the array, you could instead do:

```js
var movies = [
  { movieName: "bee movie", grade: 3, position: 1},
  { movieName: "Shrek", grade: 5, position: 2},
  { movieName: "Incredibles", grade: 4, position: 1}, 
  { movieName: "Bolt", grade: 5, position: 2}
];

var arrayPosition = 1

console.log(movies[arrayPosition].movieName)
```

Remember that:

> [JavaScript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1.
>
> Using an invalid index number returns undefined.